# Why 1.03 + 4.4 = 5.430000000000001

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

This question is just for curiosity:

I am trying to compute the following calculation in Chrome and Safari console:

```
console.log(1.03 + 4.4); // 5.430000000000001 as output
```

I want to know why this difference happens, and why the output isn't just **5.43**

If I try with different numbers there is no problem.

I think this is related with how Javascript represents the float points. But this is just a guess.

Any information is welcome

Comment: It's because floating point math. http://0.30000000000000004.com

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate, thanks